# Normal Map Bake Problem

Tags: normal-map

I'd like to bake a normal map for a simple object, but unfortunately, after the bake, the edges of the low poly model are visible on the normal map.
The image size is 1024x1024px, if I increase the size it's better, at 4096x4096px it's barely but still visible. Auto Smooth turned off for both objects and set to Smooth Shaded, also there are no sharp edges.

Is this how it should look like or there is something that I didn't take into account?

Images: [1024px normal map](https://i.imgur.com/h2vrzyT.png), [image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB6Wb.jpg).

[image]

Comment: When setting up your bake texture, did you enable 32-bit float (highly recommended)?

Comment: I tried with and also without it. The result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option here is to add holding loops to the low poly.  The triangulation won't matter if we're interpolating between vertex normals that all point in the same direction:

[image]

I just selected the top faces and 'i' inset.  Now you can see that the artifacts in the low poly's normals disappeared.  Note that they didn't go away entirely: they still exist on the edge.  We've just confined the artifacts to a small enough portion of the mesh that we'll never ever notice.  When we bake, that inset portion will be 100% okay:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!

If I understand correctly, these edge lines on the normal map can't be removed totally, it just can be reduced to a level where it's hard to notice, right? Is it true to any normal map and just I didn't notice it yet or just to flat surfaces like in this case?

Comment: I tried your first advice, to reduce the extrusion value. I baked a normal map with the same value you used, but unfortunately, I couldn't see any difference between this one and a map baked with a higher extrusion value.
Can it be caused due to some settings?

Also thanks for sharing your technique to estimate the extrusion value.

The second advice works pretty well, but of course, this requires more vertices, that is in this case wouldn't mean that much, but I'd like to avoid it if it's possible and try to figure out the first option, or maybe some alternative.

Comment: Yes, there are basically always going to be some artifacts, and the best you can do is minimize them.  You make stuff to the quality you need, not to some unattainable perfect.  It may be possible that I'm misunderstanding your problem; I couldn't see the issue in your pics, and focused on the issue that I could see in the file.

Comment: Based on your useful answers, I believe you understand my problem correctly.

One more thing that is unclear: when you reduce the extrusion value, in this specific case, do you get a visible better result with the value of 0.005? Because I get the same result even if I use a lot higher value like 0.2.

Comment: It looked better to me, but your issue was subtle to begin with.  Don't look at the image; look at the normal map in use on your mesh.

Comment: Yes, I checked it on the mesh. The problem is only visible from some angles. So to check if there is a difference I baked two separate normal maps with different values and changed them on the mesh. I kept the same angle the same view, the only thing I changed is the two normal maps vice versa, but unfortunately, I couldn't see the difference. If you had any idea why is your bake result better, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: It might be in my head :)  I'm not sure my reasoning holds up.  I mean, I believe the altered normals, combined with distance to mesh, is reason for the lines.  But now my thinking is that ray extrusion wouldn't do anything to fix it.  I may do some more testing and edit the answer.

Comment: I've done some more experimentation.  I was wrong about the ray extrusion (and deleted it from the answer.)  However, simply increasing the texel density-- either by baking to a 4k, or by increasing the space taken up on the UV map-- seems to reduce the problem.  With a 4k bake, I can't see the triangulation until the point that I can also see the quantization from using an 8 bit-per-channel image.  Strangely, downscaling that 4k back to 1k-- either as a normal bake or as emission-- has the triangles coming back.  Hope that's of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks for the correction and your effort in trying to find a solution. I think I'm going to stick with the second solution and I rather use some extra vertices than a very high-res image.

Comment: An alternative is an object space normal map, which is baking fine.  Unfortunately, again, rebaking that to tangent gets the same issue.